# redux-saga: why does `yield call (func, params)` fail but `yield call (()=>func(params))` succeed?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, redux-saga, aws-amplify

Here is my code that fails at the line with the comment `//fails`:

```
import {API} from "aws-amplify";

function* watchSitesRequested(dispatch) {
  const watchAction = ('SITES_FETCH_REQUESTED');
  const APIname="MyAPIGatewayAPI";
  const APIpath="/configmagic/sites";
  const APIinit={
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    response: true,
  };
  while (true) {
    yield take(watchAction);
    try {
      const request = yield call(API.get, APIname, APIpath, APIinit); //fails
      yield put({type: "SITES_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", payload: {sites: request.data}});
    } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "SITES_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message})
    }
  }
}
```

Console error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_api' of null
    at API.js:298
    at step (API.js:137)
    at Object.next (API.js:67)
    at API.js:39
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    [snip]
```

But if I change the call to API.get as follows, it behaves as desired:

```
const request = yield call(() => API.get(APIname, APIpath, APIinit))
```

Why?

`yield call()` I think is supposed to accept multiple parameters after the function, and it should behave fine with the `Promise` that `API.get()` returns, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
const request = yield call([API, API.get], APIname, APIpath, APIinit)
```

or

```
const request = yield call([API, 'get'], APIname, APIpath, APIinit)
```

This is because `API` is an [instance](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/api/src/index.ts) of the [class `APIClass`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/api/src/API.ts).

Javascript has [crazy rules of passing `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) when calling an instance method. Basically, it only works as intended when you directly write `API.get()` in code. But when you shedule a call via a `call` effect, the effect object only stores `API.get` function reference, losing `this` reference.

For `this` to be passed correctly, you should use [`call([context, fn], ...args)`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fn-args).